# A function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ which is differentiable at a point but not $C^1$ at that point.

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

Give me an example of a function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ which is differentiable at a point but not $C^1$ at that point.

I have found a function $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$, $f(x,y)=|xy|$ which is differentiable at $(0,0)$ but not $C^1$ at that point.
But can't find one example in $\Bbb R$.

Moreover can anyone Give me an example of a function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ which is differentiable at a point ,$C^1$ at that point but not differentiable at that point.

Comment: Ohh okay I have found one $f(x)= x^2 sin(\frac 1x)$ if $x\neq 0$ and $0$ if $x=0$ this is differentiable but not $C^1$. What for the next question?

Comment: what does "derivable" mean?

Comment: I use it for differentiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question take $$
f\left( x \right) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x},\,\,x \ne 0 \\ 
 0,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x = 0 \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
$$ $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ but the derivative not continuous at $x=0$. Moreover,
$$
f'\left( x \right) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
  - \cos \frac{1}{x} + 2x\sin \frac{1}{x},\,\,x \ne 0 \\ 
 0,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x = 0 \\ 
 \end{array} \right.$$

For the second take  $$
f\left( x \right) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 x^3 \sin \frac{1}{x},\,\,x \ne 0 \\ 
 0,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x = 0 \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
$$ $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and the derivative is continuous at $x=0$ but $f'$ is not differentiable at $x=0$ (not twice differentible). Moreover,
$$
f'\left( x \right) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 3x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x} - x\cos \frac{1}{x},\,\,x \ne 0 \\ 
 0,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x = 0 \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
$$